# How should we interpret r_c in continuously compounded interest?

Tags: interest-rates, finance, interest, compounding

I'm just curious there is any useful "meaning" or interpretation we can assign directly to $r_c$. Of course one can directly calculate the non-continuously compounded interest from $r_c$, but exactly *is* $r_c$ itself? (e.g. it is NOT the rate at which something is being infinitely compounded by). Perhaps I am just being obtuse here and it's really obvious.

To give a more concrete example: Say \$100 grows to \$120 in a given time period. $r_c \approx 18.23\%$, but what does this number really represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add to the previous answer that it simplifies the maths around working with a large number (i.e. tending to infinity) of timesteps when modelling options and other derivatives.

Comment: Yes: it simplifies the maths when working in continuous time.That is why people use it. And yet the resuts are not very far from those gotten with other interest methods/conventions.

Comment: Yes, I understand the math behind it but just thought it be nice to have something to symbolically think of it as. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score -1):

I would say it is more of theoretical concept and does not have any meaning in real world. In real world you cannot have infinite number of periods (what is an example of infinity in real world?). Moreover, the difference between fixed periods and continuous won't be much anyway.